# How to install RHadoop packages (Rmr, Rhdfs, Rhbase)?

Tags: r, hadoop, rhadoop

Actually I am trying my level best to integrate with R, but I got this error.

*packages ‘rmr’, ‘rJava‘, ‘RJSONIO‘, ‘rhdfs’, ‘rhbase’, ‘plyrmr’ are not available (for R version 3.1.3)*

**Steps to integrate Hadoop with R:**

Installed R, and Hadoop in ubuntu.

Add these three lines in ~/.bashrc file.

*export HADOOP_PREFIX=/Users/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2

export HADOOP_CMD=/Users/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop

export HADOOP_STREAMING=/Users/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.1.2.jar*

Installed R packages by using this command

```
install.packages(c("rJava", "RJSONIO", "rmr", "rhdfs", "rhbase", "plyrmr").
```

But i got above error. What is the main problem how to integrate R and Hadoop.
I have followed this [link to integrate](http://www.rdatamining.com/big-data/r-hadoop-setup-guide).

Comment: `install.packages(c("rJava", "RJSONIO", "rmr", "rhdfs", "rhbase", "plyrmr"))` This should work. What's the error?

Comment: It's installed, but after installation again getting same error.
............
The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpxWl14C/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
packages ‘rmr’, ‘rhdfs’, ‘rhbase’ are not available (for R version 3.1.3)

Comment: They may have been archived (if it is no longer maintained and no longer passes R CMD check tests). Please refer following links: (1) https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202612573-package-is-not-available-for-R-version-3-1-1-  (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-warning

Comment: You have to follow the installation instructions. If you follow your instincts, you will fail.

Answer (score 9):

Download packages rhdfs, rhbase, rmr2 and plyrmr from https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki and install them as below :

```
install.packages("<path>/rhdfs_1.0.8.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
install.packages("<path>/rmr2_2.2.2.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
install.packages("<path>plyrmr_0.2.0.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
install.packages("<path>/rhbase_1.2.0.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: Great advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

With `devtools` you can install directly from Github:

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github(c('RevolutionAnalytics/rmr2/pkg', 'RevolutionAnalytics/plyrmr/pkg'))
```

Comment: This way you get the current snapshot, not a release. If your data center burns down to smoldering ashes, blame yourself. It's true that even the releases are provided as is with no warranty, but at least they have been tested.

Comment: @piccolbo What kind of monsters aren't testing their master branch?

Comment: Friendly monsters, like the ones in Sesame Street. I haven't been on this project for a while but the full test suite took hours. It was massive and it was fantastic in ironing out bugs, but we couldn't run it on every commit. Just didn't have the resources. The other thing is that the meaning of master depends on your branching model. Some shops want it to be constantly deployable or actually deploy it on commit. Since we didn't want anyone to install anything but an official release, that was a non-goal for us.

Answer (score 1):

can you try to install these packages by specifying the reposetory:

```
install.packages(c("rJava", "RJSONIO", "rmr", "rhdfs", "rhbase", "plyrmr"), repos="http://cran.r-project.org/")
```

Comment: They aren't on CRAN. Try again

Answer (score 1):

You can download the packages from CRAN's website and install them without connecting to the repository.

For example, to download 'rJava' package, you can visit this link:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html

From there, download the 'Package source', and install them manually like this:

```
install.packages('path to downloads/rJava_0.9-6.tar.gz',repos=NULL)
```

You can follow the same pattern for the other mentioned packages. The rhdfs, rhbase and rmr packages are located at   https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Confusing, the are not on CRAN so you can't download them from there. The rest sounds about right.