# Cannot install RHDFS for RStudio (R version 3.3.1)

Tags: r, windows, hadoop, rstudio, hortonworks-data-platform

I am having problem installing rhdfs via the RStudio gui using the command

```
install.packages(rhdfs")
```

The exact error I'm receiving is -

```
Warning in install.packages
    package 'rmr' is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

I need to install the following packages:

> rJava, RJSONIO, rhbase, plyrmr, rmr, rhdfs

I have succesfully installed rJava and RJSONIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the latest version of R the 'rmr' package is probably no longer maintained.
Though you may be able to get it as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935558/983722) the surprising thing  here is that you seem to need it.

Based on the documentation in the comment by @abhiieor you should need 'rmr2' and not 'rmr'.

My suggestions:

1. Install 'rmr2' and try if that allows you to install 'rhdfs'
2. If that somehow fails via the way you try it, try to install the packages in the way that is described on this site: https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/Installing-RHadoop-on-RHEL (it also contains files for windows)

Comment: So I receive the following error - 
package 'rmr2' is not available (for R version 3.3.1) Is it possible those packages cannot be installed from the RStudio interface ?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded the files (plymr,ravro,rhbase,rhdfs,rmr2) either per the website. They were placed into my R\win-library\3.3. folder