# How to install Rhadoop on R 3.3.2?

Tags: r, hadoop, rhadoop, rmr2

I tried the following mentioned by Jinith:

[How to install RHadoop packages (Rmr, Rhdfs, Rhbase)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646482/how-to-install-rhadoop-packages-rmr-rhdfs-rhbase)

But I got this exception:

*"Installing package into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
Warning: invalid package ‘/home/user/Downloads/rmr2_3.3.2.tar.gz’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/home/user/Downloads/rmr2_3.3.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status"*

I have no idea what should I do... :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume you downloaded the Rhadoop's rmr2.tar.gz package. if you didnt, then perhaps you were trying to run `install.packages("rmr2", dependencies = TRUE)`. The error `non-zero exit status` is an installation error. If i downloaded the file in question and moved it to my D: drive in folder Rhadoop and ran the following command. The result was extracted to a folder called RHadoop under my working directory.then try to unzip the file with `untar` function.
  `untar("D:/RHadoop/rmr2.tar.gz", compressed = "gzip")`
After you've done that, you can source the .R files `source('rmr2.R')`