# Writing on HDFS an R data.frame

Tags: r, hdfs

**Back ground**

I managed to read a file with command:

```
dataSet = fread("/usr/bin/hadoop fs -text /pathToMyfile/test.csv")
```

**My problem:**

And I would like to write it (after some transformation) into test2:

```
fwrite(dataSet, file = "| /usr/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal  -f  - /pathToMyfile/test2.csv")
```

**My error:**

But this throw the following error:

```
Error in fwrite(dataSet, file = "| /usr/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal  -f  - /pathToMyfile/test2.csv") : 
  No such file or directory: '| /usr/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal  -f  - /pathToMyfile/test2.csv'. Unable to create new file for writing (it does not exist already). Do you have permission to write here, is there space on the disk and does the path exist?
```

**Something that I tryed successfully**

I got my command by testing with R function `write`

```
write("test", file =  "| /usr/bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal  -f  - /pathToMyfile/test2.csv",)
```

This work perfectly (meaning that I have writing access).

Please note, that here I am writting a string since write is not designed to write data.frame.

**Something that I tryed without any success**

I tried to repace `fwrite` by `write.csv` and `write.table` but I got the same error.

I know that rhdfs package exist, but I can't install it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work**

I'm assuming that fwrite() is from `data.table`.  If so, it wants to open up a distinct file handle and isn't taking the directive that instead of a file it should push data into the pipe that you specify.  You kind of lucked out with base::file() in that it specifically looks for and handles the pipe case (as it notes in the docs).

**If you really need to use data.table::fwrite()**

You could write an Rscript (or littler) that was totally silent other than data.table::fwrite() called without any args (which will print the output to stdout) and pipe the results of that script to your hdfs commands.

**If you're open to other approaches**

write.csv() and readr::write_csv() both accept connections and you can probably work something out with pipe().  It might be as simple as...

```
p_in <- pipe('/usr/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal  -f  - /pathToMyfile/test2.csv', 'w')
write.csv(dataSet, p_in)
close(p_in)
```

... but it might not. :)

The question asker reports that...

```
p_in <- pipe('/usr/bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -f - /pathToMyfile/test2.csv', 'w')
sink(file = p_in)
data.table::fwrite(dataSet)
sink()
close(p_in)
```

... worked well (combining this answer and the previous one).  I promoted it up here to my answer just in case someone missed it in the comments.

**If you have patience and don't mind rJava making forks impossible**

As @rob said in their answer RevolutionAnalytics has [some code](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rhdfs/tree/master/pkg/R) along these lines.  You said you couldn't install it, so it might not be a real 'answer' for this question.  However, other folks may have the same question without the same restriction, so I include it here.

Note that the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646482/how-to-install-rhadoop-packages-rmr-rhdfs-rhbase) is to install from the tested/official [releases](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/Downloads), [installation instructions](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/Installing-RHadoop-on-RHEL).

Lately Microsoft has been switching RevolutionAnalytics links over to their own stuff (they accidentally nuked MRAN just the other day). So, I'm not sure how stable that link is and/or if you can trust that it is and will be maintained (last commit to that repo was 4 years ago, but other stuff in the same family received commits ~2 or 3 years ago).  It looks like @piccolbo was a contributor to that package and has been active on StackOverflow, perhaps they'll comment on whether that package has long term support / is already rock solid.

Comment: Thanks, yes I speak about `data.table::fwrite`. I want to use it because it is way faster than write.csv.

Comment: Regarding fwrite: with your advice I did: `p_in <- pipe('/usr/bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal  -f  - /pathToMyfile/test2.csv', 'w');
sink(file = p_in);
fwrite(dataSet);
sink();
close(p_in)` Is it what you suggested, is there a better way?

Comment: Note: with this method, `fwrite` is 4 time faster than `write.csv` and 3 time faster than `write_csv`

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin Sharp thinking!  That's a great work-around.  I didn't think of sink().  There may very well be a better way, but we're at the limits of my current knowledge.